# Adding other cms community connection fails to load in header

Tags: community, header

I'm currently experimenting a bit with setting up a CMS connection from a community towards an external other system (Heroku).

On Heroku I host the following header.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styling.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="overlay">
        <h1>Test1</h1>
        <h3>Test2</h3>
        <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero nostrum quis, odio veniam itaque ullam debitis qui magnam consequatur ab. Vero nostrum quis, odio veniam itaque ullam debitis qui magnam consequatur ab.</p>
        <br>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

In the header on the community I see that it is loaded in correctly HTML wise
[image: HTML Verification]

However, I still receive the following response

```
Can't connect to server.
The server returned code HTTP 415. The URL is valid but the response from the server isn't supported.
```

I tried searching for formatting/tags that are not allowed but I do not seem to find anything related to this issue.
Furthermore, I copied a working HTML in the community and deployed it to Heroku but this also lead to nothing.
As the HTML is pretty simple, I ran out of ideas to make it work.

Any suggestions?